# How to accept cookie from iPhone, login page

Tags: php, web-applications, cookies, web, login-script

I don't know what is wrong with this php script but it makes the remember log-in for the device iPhone stop working (will log out every time when refresh the page) but the other device such as iPad, and all the PCs still can use remember me function still.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['link'])){ 
    $link = 1; 
} else { 
    $link = $_GET['link']; 
}

if ($link == 1) {
echo "";
} elseif ($link == 23) {
echo "";
} else {
echo "";
} 
?>
```

so every single time the device refresh it will redirect to the login page again

but then if I remove this script then it will remember the login

any help will be appreciated

Comment: please post your relevant code (header redirects etc)

Comment: sorry about that I forgot that part

here I added on the post

Answer (score 1):

Use session_set_cookie_params on the header:

```
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
```